# SNMP System view not returning memory information

Tags: debian, snmp, debian-lenny

I've configured SNMP properly (Removed the paranoia user and alike) and set it up with Zenoss, however it seems that Zenoss can't get the memory info from the server.

snmpwalk also shows no memory info while it seems that the system view should list it, views are as follows:

```
#           incl/excl subtree                                 mask
view all    included  .1                                      80
view system included  .iso.org.dod.internet.mgmt.mib-2.system
```

Can anyone see something wrong with this ?

Thank you for your time and attention, Xeross

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To monitor a Debian system from Zenoss I make these below changes from the stock snmpd configuration.  Then you will use `yoursnmphere` to connect from zenoss.

```
--- a/snmp/snmpd.conf
+++ b/snmp/snmpd.conf
@@ -63,2 +63,3 @@ com2sec paranoid  default         public
 #com2sec readwrite default         private
+com2sec readonly  default         yoursnmphere

@@ -108,4 +109,4 @@ access MyRWGroup ""      any       noauth    exact  all    a

-syslocation Unknown (configure /etc/snmp/snmpd.local.conf)
-syscontact Root <root@localhost> (configure /etc/snmp/snmpd.local.conf)
+syslocation Organization Name
+syscontact Contact Name
```

Also adjust this.

```
--- a/default/snmpd
+++ b/default/snmpd
@@ -10,3 +10,3 @@ SNMPDRUN=yes
 # snmpd options (use syslog, close stdin/out/err).
-SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid 127.0.0.1'
+SNMPDOPTS='-Lsd -Lf /dev/null -u snmp -I -smux -p /var/run/snmpd.pid'
```

I use the local host firewall to limit SNMP requests to only coming from zenoss and a couple other management hosts.

Comment: I already have something similar to that, but somehow it doesn't return details about memory and alike, this happens on 2 systems, that are configured identically, do you need the entire config to help ?